# How to dynamically embed a XAML/Codebehind pair as a child of a StackPanel?

Tags: wpf

I have a StackPanel called "MainContent".

I can dynamically fill it with UIElements like this:

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = String.Format("This is text");
textBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige);
MainContent.Children.Add(textBlock);

Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "This is a button";
MainContent.Children.Add(button);
```

But I want to go beyond that and fill it with a XAML/Codebehind pair (e.g. Page or Window):

```
Type type = this.GetType();
Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;
Window window = (Window)assembly.CreateInstance(String.Format("{0}.{1}", type.Namespace, "Test1"));
MainContent.Children.Add(window);
```

But the above code complains that I can't add a "Window to a Visual". I can do window.ShowDialog() of course but then it is external to my main window. 
I want the Test1 window to be *embedded* in my application.

How can I do this?

**Added:** The main question is: how can I get Window (or Page) to act as a UIElement so I can embed them dynamically in StackPanels, etc.  Currently looking at **XamlLoader**, anyone experienced with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have your XAML/code behind inherit from UserControl - and then everything will just work

Comment: bingo, that's exactly what I was trying to do, so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible. But instead of filling the panel with a Window, why not fill it with the root element of the window instead. You'll get all the content and value of the window without the unneeded chrome.

Update: you can grab the root element of a window via the Dependency Property `Content`

```
    Window w;
    object rootElement = w.Content;
```

Comment: Sounds great, how to I get the "root element of the window dynamically", e.g. window.LayoutRoot, window.RootElement, window.Children[0]... what is the syntax?

Comment: MainContent.Children.Add((UIElement)rootElement) compiles but gets a runtime error. That's the problem, how can I cast the Window into a UIElement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
MainContent.Children.Add(window.Content);
```

Comment: good idea but unfortunately intellisense shows me no "Child" for window

Comment: that should be window.Content

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code.  Still, you get my point.  Did that work?

Comment: but MainContent.Children.Add() needs a UIElement and window.Child is not a UIElement. I can cast it as such and it compiles but gets a rutime error. How can I get window to successfully act as a UIElement?